# How to pass the same JavaScript function on every different CustomValidator?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

I've a UserControl that I insert within a WebForm many times (such as 10 times).
Inside the UserControl, I've a CustomValidator:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ClientValidationFunction='CustomValidatorSesso' 
                    ValidationGroup="richiestaIscrizione" 
                    Runat="server" 
                    ID="cvSesso" 
                    onservervalidate="CustomValidatorSesso_ServerValidate" >
                    &nbsp;*
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

It must check the status of two checkboxes: `chbMaschio` and `chbFemmina` (which are inside the UserControl).

On client side, I need (for each user control) to check if at least one of them are checked (for each UserControl), and inform (I will, with ValidationSummery) which UserControl has both field empty.

In few words: each UserControl is a "person" and I need to check if the user set the gender (M or F). If not, show which person hasn't set it.

I've added this function within the UserControl

```
function CustomValidatorSesso(oSrc, args) {
    if (!$("#<%=chbFemmina.ClientID%>").is(":checked") && !$("#<%=chbMaschio.ClientID%>").is(":checked")) {
        args.IsValid = false;
    }
}
```

But this won't work, since it will place 10 times the same Javascript function in the DOM. How can I call the same javascript function for a specific UserControl?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with CheckBoxes unfortunately. But you can with other Controls that can use a `CustomValidator`, like TextBoxes:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:CustomValidator ClientValidationFunction="CustomValidatorSesso"
    ValidationGroup="richiestaIscrizione"
    runat="server"
    ID="cvSesso" ControlToValidate="CheckBox1">
</asp:CustomValidator>

<script type="text/html">
    function CustomValidatorSesso(oSrc, args) {
        if (args.Value.length > 3) {
            args.IsValid = true;
        } else {
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I got a way, if you need in the future (code behind): `        cvSesso.ClientValidationFunction= "CustomValidatorSesso" + mIndexZeroBased;
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "CustomValidatorSesso" + mIndexZeroBased, "function CustomValidatorSesso" + mIndexZeroBased + "(oSrc, args) { if (!$('#" + chbFemmina.ClientID+ "').is(':checked') && !$('#" + chbMaschio.ClientID + "').is(':checked')) { args.IsValid = false; } }", true);`